# PHP IF Statement Evaluation & Server Overhead

Tags: php, optimization, evaluation, overhead

I'm curious what the impact on the server is when PHP if statements are evaluated, i.e. memory consumption and CPU usage and if this could become a major issue as traffic grows?

For example, if I use a lot of PHP IF statements in the theme for each post summary on a WordPress blog, is this going to require a great deal more server resources if the home page starts getting high traffic? And, on pages where many posts are listed (i.e. category pages) , it seems like this could become a problem.

I'm thinking it may be good idea to pare down the IF statements that aren't absolutely necessary in the event that traffic spikes. Or, is this even something I be worrying about?

Answer (score 10):

The time spent evaluating 1000s of `if` statement will be completely overwhelmed by a single database query.

You need to:

1. **Profile** to find out where your  bottlenecks are
2. **Focus** - if a function takes 50% of the total time then making it 10% faster will have more effect than making a teeny function 90% faster.

Edit:

Database queries *are* slow (even a quick one) - you should aim to make as few queries as possible, within reason.
Within a query, I don't think there's a speed difference between checking for NULL or a specific value - if there is it will be a minuscule difference.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Most of the IF statements I'm using check for values in the database i.e. IF NOT NULL or if a specific value exists. So then, the IF statement itself may not be an issue, but the fact that it is creating a database query is. Is there any difference between checking if a field is not null vs. checking if the field has a specific value related to the current post?

Comment: +1 for adding "within reason" as a caveat to your DB queries warning. Do not try to condense queries to the point that they are so ridiculously complex that they just cause more overhead anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is something you don't have to worry about : if your application does one or two queries to the database, those will take much more time than a couple (even more than a couple) of "if".

This is kind of "micro-optimization" : if you are looking for big optimizations in the event of a traffic spike, there are other ways that should be explored first ;-)

For some (quite longer) explanations / ideas, you can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260134/optimizing-kohana-based-websites-for-speed-and-scalability/1283195#1283195) I gave yesterday to another question.

*(I really don't feel like rewriting any of that before at least a couple of days have passed ^^ )*

Basically, what can really help is :

- Using an opcode cache, like [APC](http://pecl.php.net/package/APC)
- Using caching : the more data you cache, the less calculations / DB queries you have to make -- and those are the one that generally take the most important amount of time
- Using [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) and it's profiling abilities, to identify what takes time in your application
- Optimizing SQL queries, using the right indexes
- If you want to go farther, you can use a reverse-proxy to act as another level of cache ; for instance, [varnish](http://varnish.projects.linpro.no/).

Comment: @downvoter : I'm fine with being downvoted : it's part of the way SO works ; but I would **really** like to know what is wrong in what I say : this is the only way I won't do that mistake on the next website I'll give optimization advices for... If what I said is plain wrong, tell me : I need to know so I don't say the same sh*t again the next time !
(and, btw, I have the same feeling when other people get downvoted : not explaining what was wrong is sometimes plain rude, and doesn't help anyone understanding what could be done better :-( )

Comment: Hi Pascal. Thank you for the answer. How about eAccelerator? That is what I currently have installed. I've seen a couple people recommend APC so I'm wondering if it is better.

Comment: Hi, I've never used eAccelerator, and always heard about APC in great terms, so I can't really say ; sorry...

Answer (score 2):

Nothing to worry about, at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking we need to give a more logical reason why it doesnt matter.... it's because an IF statement at it's basic level in assembler comes down the the **JNZ** mnemonic. It's a 1 "word" value meaning "JUMP IF NOT ZERO". The real heavy load will come from the comparing and evaluating the conditionals, not the IF statement itself.

Comment: Which is still overshadowed by network latency, database query time, and browser rendering...