# Optimizations to reduce website loading time

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, optimization

What are some important optimizations that can be made to a website to reduce the loading time?

Comment: My all time fav http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Remove/Minimize any bottlenecks on the server side. For this purpose, use a profiler like Xdebug or Zend Debugger to find out where your application is doing expensive and slow operations. Implement caching where possible. Use an OpCode Cache. If this still isn't fast enough consider investing in more CPU or RAM or SSDs (depending on whether you are CPU, IO or Memory bound)

For general server/client side optimizations, see the Yahoo [YSlow! User Guide](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/help/index.html).

It basically sums it up to:

> 1. Minimize HTTP Requests
> 2. Use a Content Delivery Network
> 3. Add an Expires or a Cache-Control Header
> 4. Gzip Components
> 5. Put StyleSheets at the Top
> 6. Put Scripts at the Bottom
> 7. Avoid CSS Expressions
> 8. Make JavaScript and CSS External
> 9. Reduce DNS Lookups
> 10. Minify JavaScript and CSS
> 11. Avoid Redirects
> 12. Remove Duplicate Scripts
> 13. Configure ETags
> 14. Make AJAX Cacheable
> 15. Use GET for AJAX Requests
> 16. Reduce the Number of DOM Elements
> 17. No 404s
> 18. Reduce Cookie Size
> 19. Use Cookie-Free Domains for Components
> 20. Avoid Filters
> 21. Do Not Scale Images in HTML
> 22. Make favicon.ico Small and Cacheable

Also see the comments contributed below, as they contain some additional useful information for other users.

Comment: Also check out Google' PageSpeed http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/ its a good alternative/complement to YSlow and is also a Firebug addon.  It catches some things that YSlow doesn't, and vice-versa.

Comment: One more thing: Use in-memory sessions if you control enough of the server to install additional plugins and have enough RAM. The memcache plugin includes a session handler.  http://php.net/memcache

Comment: Good answer. All these things are explained in more detail on this (excellent) Yahoo article: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Comment: Google Speed Tracer is another good tool to use, it's a Chrome extension that measures a lot of different aspects of site performance: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/speedtracer/

Answer (score 3):

Before attempting any optimizations first you need to be able to profile, get [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox. Then you can run some analysis that will tell you exactly what to do using [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/). Fundamental things that you should do are listed [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html).

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few "best practice" things:

- Caching CSS, JavaScript, images, etc.
- Minifying Javascript files.
- gzip content.
- Place links to JavaScript files, JavaScript code, and links to CSS files at the bottom of your page when possible.
- Load only what is necessary.
- For an existing website, before you do any of this determine where your bottlenecks are with tools like Firebug and as someone else mentioned YSlow (I highly recommend this tool).

Answer (score 2):

There are two sides you can care about, when optimizing :

- The server side : what matters is generating the ouput faster
- The client side : what matters is getting all that has to be displayed faster.

Note : we, as developpers, often think about optimizing the server-side first... Which in most cases only represents less than 10% percent of the loading-time of the page !

On the server side, you'll generally want to :

- profile, to determine what's long
- optimize your SQL queries, and reduce their number
- use caching

For more informations, you can take a look to the answer I gave some time ago to this question : [Optimizing Kohana-based Websites for Speed and Scalability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260134/optimizing-kohana-based-websites-for-speed-and-scalability/1283195#1283195)

On the client side, the biggest gains are generally achieved by :

- Reducing the number of HTTP requests -- the easiest way being to reduce the number of JS/CSS/images files, by combining several files into one
- Compressing CSS/JS/HTML, using for instance Apache's `mod_deflate`.

About that, there is a lot of great stuff on [Yahoo's Exceptional Performance](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/) : they've released lots of [good pratices](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) and tools, such as [yslow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/).

Answer (score 2):

The simple options I can think of are:

1. Gzip (x)html, so a compressed file should arrive more quickly to the user
2. minify the CSS
3. minify the JS
4. use caching where possible
5. use a content-delivery network
6. use a tool, such as [yslow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) to identify bottlenecks and further suggestions

Answer (score 2):

definitely want to look at caching, as round trips to DB are expensive.
also, minify JS

Answer (score 2):

install firebug and pagespeed plugin 
follows all the pagespeed directives (until possible) and be happy
http://code.google.com/intl/it/speed/page-speed/

anyway the most importante optimization in my experience is to reduce the number of HTTP requests to a minimum...

Answer (score 2):

We recently did this on our web site. Here we outlined nine techniques that seemed to have the highest impact with the least difficulty: http://mentormate.com/blog/easy-ways-speed-website-load-time/

Answer (score 1):

The first optimisation is: Decide if it is slow, and if not, don't bother.

This is trickier than it sounds, because it's not like testing a desktop app or game. A game is slow if when you play it on the target hardware, the frame rate is too low. This is very easy to measure.

A web site is trickier, because you, as the developer, are probably using a local test system with a very fast network. Even when you use your staging / system test servers, you're probably still on the local network. Even your production servers are in all likelihood, on the same continent.

The same is possibly not true for quite a lot of your users.

Therefore the options which exist are:

- Find out by asking your users, whether they find it to be slow
- Simulate a high latency environment and test it yourself (or your QA team)
- Guesswork

The latter is not recommended.

An option which the holier-than-thou Yahoo Web Sites performance book (which yes, is a book you can buy) doesn't mention a lot is HTTPS. Most web applications which handle important data run mostly or entirely over HTTPS, which changes the rules of the game rather a lot. Remember to do all testing with it enabled.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, you can use Yslow or PageSpeed firefox extension. But you can also use [GTmetrix](http://gtmetrix.com/), an online service scanning your page with both tools.

Features I like / use:

- soft, clean and usable presention
- comparison with another page. It's really interesting to see where are your friends / competitors.

(by the way, i'm not related to gtmetrix !)

Answer (score 0):

To reduce network traffic, you can minify static files, such as CSS and Javascript, and use gzip compression on generated content. You can also try using tools such as optipng to reduce the size of images.

However, the first step to take is to actually analyse what's taking all of the time -- whether it's sending the bits over the network, or actually generate the content to send. There's no point making your CSS files 10% smaller if it takes a minute to generate each HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use whitespace in code.

Answer (score -3):

Load balancing would help to reduce the loading time immense.

Comment: No, it wouldn't, in almost all cases.