# How to reduce website load time

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, web

I have made resume website http://rupeshgharat.com

I want to reduce load time

Any response will be appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Optimizations to reduce website loading time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359515/optimizations-to-reduce-website-loading-time)

Comment: I think there is more than an Optimization problem going on there. 2 or 3 minutes!!!

Comment: It loads instantly for me...

Comment: Go to http://www.webpagetest.org/ and run your URL through it. It will tell you what is happening and how long each takes. You're loading a bunch of stuff and not using GZip.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Google' PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/). It gives a detailed information about every file causing delay and what is the remedy for that.

But i guess in your case something else is wrong, because unoptimized website doesn't take 2-3 minutes to load. Its a very long time.

Comment: I was about to say the same +1, don't understand why someone voted down. It's a big topic, not only about the page optimizing itself, the biggest factor to me is server speed,  and I'm sure the OP has to do some research to figure that out.

Comment: He's got 175 requests while loading - server speed has nothing to do with that. Even on best server would be way to much, and loading would be very long.

Comment: I dont think so @plunntic .. Server speed ofcourse matters.. It is taking 800ms to fetch this little CSS http://rupeshgharat.com/css/prettyPhoto.css

Comment: Yep @void, but if you have about 10-15 files with your assets then the page - even on crappy servers - loads in normal time. Not like that. So changing a server, when in fact you've got bad design is not a solution.

Comment: I have voted up but the link u gave for google speed is dead. However a search in google for google page speed will take you there

Answer (score 0):

Generally the most time-consuming when it comes to websites is establishing new connection for any request. Every asset (i mean one asset file) request means for example 10ms of connection establishing and then only 2-3ms of downloading. That's why it is important to concatenate your assets. Then you got one big `scripts.js` file. Downloading time increases to let's say 30ms, but the establishing time decreases ([your_old_js_assets_count]-1)*10ms. And adequately with other assets types (one *.css file, one big .png texture atlas, etc). And after all, you have a big gain.

And now. You've got 175! requests on your site. That's bad. Really bad. You should keep it below 10 on a site like that. If you do so, the site should load in normal time (in about few seconds).

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the javascript below the footer, JS takes a long time to load. This will allow the page to load then the JS to load in the background. The best format:

1. CSS at the top in the header.
2. HTML under the css.
3. Javascript at the bottom of the file.

EDIT:

It looks like you have it so the page only shows when everything is loaded. Only server/client internet speed can connection will speed the page up.

Comment: It won't do anything, he's got 175 request while loading :)

Answer (score 0):

Your page is loading faster than it appears (about 6 seconds), but it seems like there is a request to the Google map api hanging. So the preloader you have set up on your site to make a smooth fade in once everything is loaded is making it appear that nothing is loading. Remove the preloader, and let your site show up as it loads. Or figure out why the map api is hanging and that should fix it too.

The easy fix is just to delete or comment out the following css. from your `main.css` file

```
#preloader {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
min-height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: #ffffff;
z-index: 9999;
}
```

However as others have mentioned your site could use some TLC to cut down the number of requests. You have far too many.

Comment: Thanks buddy .solution save my 20 sec load time