# Website DOMContentLoaded fast but Favicon Always Load after 21 Seconds? Why?

Tags: php, performance, favicon, domcontentloaded

My website, https://homegift.vn, has a performance problem: DOMContentLoaded only 2s, but the `favicon.ico` always loads after 20s.

NOTE that:

- This was not happening before and I have not updated the code.
- Website Assets all optimized and can load fast.
- This happens for all
  pages (DOM maybe faster or slower, but all loads always finished
  after 21s with favicon).

[image]

I have tried to remove all slowing resources and third party content like Facebook.

Comment: Some code to illustrate how you load the rest of the  content would be a nice start.

Comment: This could be due to the way you're gathering the favicon, are you using a tag in the head or letting the browser automatically search for a favicon

Comment: This site using Prestashop CMS, so it managed Favicon.ico , I can see this on header:
<blink><link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="/img/favicon.ico?1528425387">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/img/favicon.ico?1528425387"></blink>

And i think this have no problem~

Comment: I can see that your theme-eec946155.css take 9.09 seconds to load.
See how to speed up page speed that can decrease your page load time than your icon load faster. Check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359515/optimizations-to-reduce-website-loading-time

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this causion by some Script with DOM loaded event, i have try remove that and all look good now!
Many thank @All