# Need help in speeding up my php based site

Tags: php, mysql, performance, caching

I'm building a site based on XAMPP on Windows. Currently it's in construction on my local machine only. Things are at good speed now.  I use ajax to load some html content onclick of somethings. It's at ok speed but after some time those ajax requests especially for loading HTML get real slow.  I enabled MySQL cache. Not much difference.

Please suggest a way to make this faster and if caching is the only option which way to go. Suggest a way so that it helps me in the future too.

Comment: 1. Is the problem occurring randomly? 2. Have you benchmarked your sql-queries to see how long they take? 3. Do you use a 3rd party framework or any 3rd party tools?

Comment: Considering we don't know how your website works, it'll be hard to give some precise advise ; but you might want to take a look at my answer on this question, for some general ideas : http://stackoverflow.com/q/1260134/138475

Comment: Install firebug, and once the site starts getting slow have a look at your console/net panel to see where all the time is going. Post the results here

Comment: Quick question, is it slow on the server side or the client side? (If you refresh the page, does it speed up?)

Comment: @Pascal MARTIN that answer you pointed to was _AWESOME_! Was looking for exactly that for a project I'm working on

Comment: @pascal - thanks as its huge it'll take some time for me to read itself

Comment: @ JV - it gets faster when it is refreshed. so what does it mean?

Comment: @ancide - 1. not randommly , 2.not yet i'll see them first, 3.no third party thing. everything is done from scratch by me

Answer (score 0):

First you will have to look at your database schema, maybe the problem is there.

- Did you look at the [slow query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/slow-query-log.html)?
- All your index are correct? (try the [explain](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) on your query to see)
- what is the size of the output HTML?
- did you enable output compression?
- how long does it takes to execute the request? (including sql, html output etc...)

Also, did you try in a LAMP environment?

**Tip**: you can use [memcached](http://memcached.org/) that will help speed up your output for large load situations.